# Reset select widget reactively

Tags: svelte

I have a page with two select widgets and the simple use case is, that the second select should be cleared when the user change the selection on the first widget.

It actually works this way, where `selectedValue1` and `selectedValue2` are the selected options from the two selects, but it feels pretty hackish

```
$: selectedValue2 = (selectedValue1) ? '' : '';
```

Is there a cleaner, more elegant implementation for such a use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an event listener:

```html
<select
  bind:value={selectedValue1}
  on:change="{() => selectedValue2 = null}"
>...</select>

<select
  bind:value={selectedValue2}
>...</select>
```

[Demo here](https://svelte.dev/repl/f0eacf3ab2a5423d9af1a66543133398?version=3.23.0). Note that I'm using `svelte-ignore a11y-no-onchange` otherwise it'll complain about the use of a `change` event, which I think is probably fine in this case.

Comment: That's much better. Thanks! I have components for the select but exposing the event is easy enough.